# Make serializable a list of undefined type

Tags: c#, session

I use this code to return a list of object to store them in out-proc session :

```
Session["Data"] = DataContext.ObjectSet.Select(rec => new { Title = rec.Title , Count = rec.Count });
```

But as you know , we can not store un-serializable class in a out-proc session, Is there any way to do this ?
Please do not say me to define its class, I am looking for a backdoor in C# or a tricks to do this

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way is to convert to an array object

```
Session["Data"] = DataContext.ObjectSet
                      .Select(rec => new { Title = rec.Title , Count = rec.Count })
                      .ToArray();
```

You can even convert it to a List oibject and serialize it into your own object

```
var data = DataContext.ObjectSet
             .Select(rec => new SessionData() { Title = rec.Title , Count = rec.Count })
             .ToList();

System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = 
     new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

Session["Data"] = oSerializer.Serialize(data);
```

and using

```
public class SessionData {
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

But holding such object in a session... you would probably doing things wrong no? Imagine in a given time you will have 1000 records for that list...

Comment: I like the first solution , I did know that I can store an array of un-serializable  in a sessions and I will check it , but what are warning meabout of?is there any thing wrong about storing about 1000 records in a sessions :-/ ?

Comment: "array of un-serializable" an Array is not un-serializable... an Array will be converted to a string, or you can force it adding `.ToString()` as that's what you can hold in a Session. An Array, it's a native object, not a custom one, so it's always serializable. Regarding **1000 records**, that's per user, per session ... you will consume all the memory from the server, and if you're hosting in a shared environment, they will stop your application from running as it will consume to many resources...

Comment: So , what is the solution ? I use this session in an other page as crystal report data source